# Core Animation Layer Degrading NSImage Quality

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsimage

So I have a view in which I need to use `Core Animation Layer`, but I have an `NSImage` inside an `image well` in the view, and when I add the `Core Animation Layer` through the interface builder, the image quality is degraded. Here's an example:

View without Core Animation Layer:

[image: View without Core Animation Layer]

Turning on Core Animation Layer:

[image: Turning on Core Animation Layer]

View with Core Animation Layer:

[image: View with Core Animation Layer]

Is there any way I could remedy this to have the Core Animation Layer and keep the image quality the same?

Comment: Why are you making the view layer backed?

Comment: In the app I'm developing I have a custom background and I had a weird bug where every time I would press a button or update the string for a label, the entire view would redraw inside the frame of the button/label. Making it layer backed solved this, but created the problem above.